# Why does Flask refuse to close connection to the database when served from Gunicorn?

Tags: mysql, flask, mariadb, gunicorn, peewee

**Edit 2:** After some sleuthing, there doesn't seem to be anything glaringly wrong. I also checked that the database was properly closing after each request (it was). Ultimately, the only thing that worked was to use Peewee's `ReconnectMixin`, which automatically reconnects to MySQL if the connection timed out.

It's probably not the ideal solution, but in case anyone else is stuck in this same scenario and happens to be using Flask + Peewee + Gunicorn + Docker, this is the change I've made to my code to grab the database:

```
class ReconnectMySQLDatabase(ReconnectMixin, MySQLDatabase):
    pass

db = ReconnectMySQLDatabase(
    database=DATABASE_NAME,
    user=DATABASE_USER,
    password=DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    charset='utf8mb4'
)
```

Again, I've confirmed that the app is explicitly managing connections. Hopefully applying this bandaid doesn't mean dispensing with best practices.

**Edit:** I did some more troubleshooting and have narrowed down the issue to Gunicorn. I tried running everything from Flask's development server and the database hasn't timed me out once. I've updated the title accordingly (it previously assumed the issue was Flask- / Peewee- related).

I still haven't figured out *what* I can configure on Gunicorn's end to fix this, but it's good to know what the source of the problem is.

---

I'm working on an app that doesn't seem to want to close its connection to the database. In my code, I'm explicitly opening and closing my connections with each request as [per this example](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#flask) in Peewee's documentation.

In addition to Flask and Peewee, I'm using [Connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion). Both the app and the database run from their own Docker container.

Here's what happens.

The first request to the server always works as expected. Subsequent requests made *before* `wait_timeout` amount of time elapses are also fine. As long as one of these requests interact with the database, the connection seems to stay alive with the timer resetting.

Requests made after `wait_timeout` amount of time elapses result in errors. The first request that fails always shows this error: `peewee.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")`. Subsequent requests show `peewee.InterfaceError: (0, '')`.

In the course of troubleshooting, I've determined the following:

- The issue is directly related to MySQL's `wait_timeout` setting; for the purposes of troubleshooting, I've taken this down from its default (`600` seconds in MariaDB) to `12` so I can more easily get feedback on whether code changes work (hint, nothing's worked so far)
- This issue applies to all requests that touch the database (read/update/insert) even for extremely trivial requests (get the value of one field in one table)
- In one troubleshooting attempt, I commented out the blocks for `@app.before_request` and `@app.teardown_request`, directly adding `g.db.connect()` and `g.db.close()` before and after queries to no avail
- Passing `reuse_if_open=True` to `g.db.connect()` results in the same errors and doesn't resolve anything
- I've also made sure to comment out any initialization code (to create tables, for example) and have tried to limit which parts of the code call `g.db.connect()` and `g.db.close()`

The database logs are as follows:

```
mysqld, Version: 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic-log (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                Id Command  Argument
200102  2:05:30      8 Connect  user@192.168.16.3 as anonymous on app
                     8 Query    SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
                     8 Query    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
                     9 Connect  user@192.168.16.3 as anonymous on app
                     9 Query    SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
                     9 Query    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
                     9 Query    SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`name`, `t1`.`value`, `t1`.`config_type_id`, `t1`.`validation_type`, `t1`.`description`, `t1`.`min_role`, `t1`.`omittable`, `t1`.`conditional_on`, `$
                     9 Query    COMMIT
                     8 Quit
                    10 Connect  user@192.168.16.3 as anonymous on app
                    10 Query    SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
                    10 Query    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
                    10 Quit
200102  2:06:13     11 Connect  user@192.168.16.3 as anonymous on app
                    11 Query    SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
                    11 Query    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
                    11 Quit
                    12 Connect  user@192.168.16.3 as anonymous on app
                    12 Query    SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
                    12 Query    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
                    12 Quit
```

Does anyone have any ideas for what I could try to get things to work? I'd like to avoid using a workaround (like setting the timeout to its max value and running some cron task to ping the DB ever x hours).

Comment: Is there some form of "connection pooling" happing in gunicorn or peewee?  Is the failure to disconnect causing a problem?  Is gunicorn a web app?

Comment: @RickJames Peewee is the ORM that I'm using in my Flask app. From what I understand, connection pooling is available, but it's not configured by default. Gunicorn is the WSGI server I'm using to serve the Flask app. When serving the app through Flask's out-of-the-box development server, everything runs fine and the database never drops a connection. It's only when served through Gunicorn does the issue appear. I've been using the workaround (using the reconnect mixin) for a few days now and that seems hold up pretty well- no issues yet.